# Hiding the resize handles in YUI library not working

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, yui

I am using Drag and Resize component from YUI libray for my web project and integrated it and both Drag and resize is working fine. But I want to hide the handles displayed when resizing the content. I had go through several examples but can't get the solution. Here is my code

```
Y.use('resize', function(Y) {       
    var resizeNode = new Y.Resize({                                   
        node : '#myNode',    
        hiddenHandles: true     
    });
)};
```

I Have tried the `hover: true` and is working fine. But i want to hide the handles forever. What actually wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this by overriding the YUI default CSS classes for resize handles:

```
.yui3-resize-handle-inner-r, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-l, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-t, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-b, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-tr, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-br, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-tl, .yui3-resize-handle-inner-bl {display:none;}
```

Update:

Looks like IE7 does not honor the above code. I was able to hide the resize handles in IE7 by adding the following:

```
.yui3-resize-handle {display:none;}
```

If you are using conditional comments for IE7, you could do something like this:

```
.ie7 .yui3-resize-handle {display:none;}
```

Comment: both 8 and 9. when we hover it to resize it don't show the resizable cursor and can't drag the target